# Bypass "Do you want to continue (y/n, default n)" for "setup.py"?

Tags: python, bash, shell, installation

I'd like to bypass the "Do you want to continue (y/n, default n)" prompt via a shell script.

I've tried:

```
python setup.py install --force
```

and

```
python setup.py install
wait
y
```

both don't work ... anyone have other ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If this question is displayed multiple times, just do a:

```
yes | command
```

However this will also aknowledge all other questions. If you want something more sophisticated have a look at [`expect`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect).

Comment: If you want to pipe something other than `yes`, simply provide it as a parameter to `yes`. For example, to submit `y` instead, type `yes y`.

Comment: @l0b0: good point. I forgot to mention this. However `y` is the default for `yes` so your example is flawed.

Answer (score 5):

Pipe the string "y" into the command.

eg:

```
echo "y" | python setup.py install
```